# PHP Facebook : Allowing my website to post to user's Facebook page on behalf

Tags: php, facebook

I've looked at how I can post to my facebook page via my PHP website (as described in http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php).

Now, this might be quite similar, what is the best way to allow another user to grant my website to post to his/her facebook page on behalf?

Comment: Also make sure to read the Facebook Platform Policy https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Answer (score 0):

You need the permissions scope `publish_actions` and then use `/page/feed`. More information at the Graph API documentation, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed#publish).